# Помогите доработать JQUERY меню

Tags: jquery

```js
$("nav div").click(function() {
  $("ul").slideToggle();
  $("ul ul").css("display", "none");
});
$("ul li").click(function() {
  $("ul ul").slideUp();
  $(this).find("ul").stop().slideToggle();
});
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() > 768) {
    $("ul").removeAttr('style');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div class="">
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Drop 1 <i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Product 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Product 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Product 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Product 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Drop 2 <i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Product 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Product 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Product 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Product 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Цитата
Помогите доработать, нужно чтобы меню закрывалось при повторном нажатии на него и при нажатии вне окна меню

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("nav > ul > li").click(function(event) {
  let ul = $(this).find("ul");
  if (ul.length && ul.is(':hover')) {
    return false;
  }
  ul.slideToggle();
  $("ul ul").not(ul).slideUp();
  event.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).on("click", function() {
  $("nav ul ul").slideUp();
});
```

```css
ul ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div class="">
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Drop 1 <i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Product 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Product 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Product 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Product 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Drop 2 <i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Product 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Product 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Product 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Product 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```